# Updating existing content in source S3 bucket doesn't replicate older versions to cross region buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I was following this lab on the cross-region replication of S3 buckets. When a pre-existing content is updated in the source bucket, only the latest/new version is getting replicated to the other bucket. Is there something that I missed. I think the content should be replicated to the destination cross-region bucket(s) along with all the previous versions. I was trying with the old S3 console.

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation s3 will not replicate objects which existed prior to replication being turned on. As such the versions of your files that existing before replication was enabled will not be replicated.

> **What Is Replicated**
>
> Any new objects created after you add a replication configuration, with exceptions described in the next section.
>
> **What Is Not Replicated**
>
> Amazon S3 does not retroactively replicate objects that existed before you added replication configuration.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/crr-what-is-isnot-replicated.html

Comment: I am aware of the fact that it should no replicate any existing objects. But, if you add a new version of an existing object which already has one/more versions, then the new version of the object should get replicated along with all the previous versions. That's the scenario right ? But it is no replicating the older versions.. only the current version is getting replicated.

Comment: ok, i understand. I just did a quick check with some text files and the older versions were pulled across after the file was updated. How do your permissions look?

Comment: Well I have public **Read** permission for both of the AWS bucket and all the versions of the object are having public Read permission as well.